# Type Error: Cannot read property 'user' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**Purpose:** To create an invite and message the guild owner once bot has joined a new guild.

**Code:** Error Location

```
client.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
    // This event triggers when the bot joins a guild.
    console.log(``)
    console.log(greenBright(`[GUILD JOINED] ${guild.name} | [ID] ${guild.id} | [ (+) MEMBERCOUNT: ${guild.memberCount}]`));
    console.log(``)

    const getOwner = guild.owner.user;
    const InviteLogGuild = client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.id === "GUILD_ID");
    const InviteLogChannel = InviteLogGuild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === "CHANNEL_ID");
    const getChennel = guild.channels.cache.first();

    getOwner.send(`Thank you for allowing lovell to  be added to your server, ${guild.name}, ${guild.owner.user.username} !\nPrefix:\`${prefix}\`\nAll commands are displayed by saying \`${prefix}help\`\nFeel free to join lovell server: ${MainServer}`)
        .then(console.log(magentaBright(`\n[GUILD OWNER MESSAGED]\n`)))
        .catch(() => {
            console.error(redBright(`\n[GUILD OWNER MESSAGE DEINIED]\n`));
        });
...
});
```

**Error:**

```
(node:9168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
```

*I've tried other ways to getting the guild owner as a `Discord#User` property but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!*

Comment: May you tell us the output of `console.log(guild.owner)`?

Comment: just, `guild.owner` or `guild.owner.user`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's null, as evidenced by the error message..

Comment: Your API response clearly does not have an object `guild.owner` which contains the property `user`, you need to look into whether you have the correct API call for what you are looking for

Comment: @mhodges indeed, but the value may change over time

Comment: [image](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/790498161533517835/803731570682363904/unknown.png) It doesnt contain the `user` property?

Comment: Would be much better to see the output of the entire `guild` object inside of the guildCreate callback

Comment: So the issue is my API orrr?

Comment: @11tracy Please post the output of `console.log(guild)` at the top of your callback function

Comment: No, the issue is that you need to figure out from the `guild` object, if you even have the data you are looking for. Otherwise you need to confirm that you are even using the **correct** API call to discord

Comment: [guild log 1](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/790498161533517835/803733172176289842/Screenshot_263.png?width=1084&height=610)

[guild log 2](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/790498161533517835/803733173238235186/Screenshot_264.png?width=1084&height=610)

[guild log 3](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/790498161533517835/803733174991192074/Screenshot_265.png?width=1084&height=610)

[guild log 4](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/790498161533517835/803733176483577896/Screenshot_266.png?width=1084&height=610)

Comment: I do have the data im looking for as it can clearly identify what property im calling [look here](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/790498161533517835/803731570682363904/unknown.png)

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild), notice that some properties listed don't appear in all endpoints, notice that OWNER has two `**` which means it only gets returned from get-current-user-guilds endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me, I have worked out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing:

```
let ThisGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(g => g.id === guild.id)
const getOwner = ThisGuild.member(ThisGuild.owner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to james pointing out that not all properties appear in all end points.

I've come up with a solution which solves the issue:

```
const Owner = guild.ownerID;
const fetchOwner = client.users.fetch(Owner);

(await fetchOwner).send(`Thank you for allowing lovell to  be added to your server, ${guild.name}, ${(await fetchOwner).username} !\nPrefix:\`${prefix}\`\nAll commands are displayed by saying \`${prefix}help\`\nFeel free to join lovell server: ${MainServer}`)
        .then(console.log(cyanBright(`[GUILD OWNER MESSAGED]`)))
        .catch(() => {
            console.error(redBright(`[GUILD OWNER MESSAGE DEINIED]`));
        });
```